# Edit CSS style to mdDialog

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to increase the source of the content of Are you sure to search without filters?

I have tried different ways and seeing the element inspector but there is no way.

I haven't found much information on this either.

Can somebody help me?

My code:

```
$scope.checkInputsAndSearch = function () {
            if (
              !$scope.datos.consulta.citaPrevia  &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.cliente &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.tipoCita  &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.fechaDesde  &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.fechaHasta &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.taller &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.tipoVehiculo &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.estado &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.municipio &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.situacion &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.autorizacion  &&
              !$scope.datos.consulta.matricula
            ) {
              var confirmDialog = $mdDialog.confirm()
                .confirm()
                .textContent("¿Estás seguro de realizar la búsqueda sin filtros?")
                .cancel("VOLVER")
                .ok("ACEPTAR")
                .theme("my-custom-dialog");
  
          $mdDialog.show(confirmDialog).then(function () {
            $scope.funciones.mostrarCitas(1);
          });

        } else {
          $scope.funciones.mostrarCitas(1);
        }
      };
```

I tried to see the class in the element inspector and modify the css code but there was no way.